# Update single view where there are many in AngularJs and UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am a n00b to Angular, and trying to get my head around how ui-routing works.  I see the how the concept of multiple routes works, and how nested routes work.  How would i do both? Or is this not good practice?

In the example bellow I have **app/wh** working fine, however when some goes to **app/wh/toc/123** I want only the middle view to swap.

```
.state('app.wh', {
                url: "/wh",
                views: {
                    'left' : {
                        templateUrl: "static/partials/leftPane.html"
                    },
                    'middle': {
                        templateUrl: "static/partials/start.html"
                    },
                    'right' : {
                        templateUrl: "static/partials/rightPane.html",
                        controller: 'AsideCtrl'
                    }
                }

            })

            .state('app.wh.toc', {
                url: "/toc/:id",

                views: {
                    'middle' : {
                        templateUrl: "static/partials/toc.html",
                        controller: function($scope, $stateParams, $state){
                            $scope.title = $stateParams.id;
                        }
                    }
                }



            })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you want your left and right panels to stay static while the middle content changes through the users actions. Personally I am not a big fan of using multiple routes, and instead simply use `ng-include` if I want to separate portions of a single view into their own files.

If you do this, then you only need to define your parent, and child state:

```
.state('app.wh', url: '/wh', abstract: true, controller: ...
```

Note that if you want separate controllers for left and right, you can use `ng-controller` in your views. Also If this state is common to multiple middle contents, then you might want to make it an abstract state, so that the user cannot actually load it (it only acts as a parent placeholder).

```
.state('app.wh.toc', url: /toc/:id ...
```

Then in your view:

```
<div ng-include="someUrlRefLeft"></div>
<div ui-view=""></div>
<div ng-include="someUrlRefRight"></div>
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was missing. I didn't feel like what i was doing was the right approach. Going to give it a shot now, thanks

Comment: Thanks ng-include actually answered a few of my other issues as well. Was relying a bit too much on ui-router